# table not found when coming back from in app browser link: Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a phone-gap application for android, save database with .db extension in assets folder , on java file of application i did copy database to my application database (code is below), now suppose i have two buttons (one for open external link and other is for open database and fetching data from db) . upon launching of application when i click for fetching data from db button its success full and execute the query , and now when i click on button for open inapp browser link from my app its open the link in inappbrowser and now i click back button and we are our application page now if i click on button for fetching the data from database its sending error "SqliteDatabaseCpp(28065): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tblProduct
"

so pls any one could suggest me where i am wrong , my code for copy database  and execute query are below:

**Java code for copy data to database:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
    this.copy("Databases.db", "/data/data/" + pName + "/app_database/");
    this.copy("0000000000000001.db", "/data/data/" + pName
            + "/app_database/file__0/");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.loadUrl(
            "file:///android_asset/www/index.html",
            2000);
    super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    super.appView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

 // Copy Paste this function in the class where you used above part
void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {

Log.d("GRT", "We are in the copy of db");
File CheckDirectory;
CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
if (!CheckDirectory.exists()) {
    Log.d("GRT", "Creating copy of db db");
    CheckDirectory.mkdir();
} else {
    Log.d("GRT", "Databse already exists");
}

InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder + file);

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
in.close();
out.close();

}
```

**HTML buttons(one for open inappbrowser and other is query for database):**

```
 <a data-role="button" onclick="openInapp()">open inapp browser</a>
```

```
 <a  data-role="button" onclick="queryRecommded()">View Recommended Product</a>
```

**corresponding .js file code is :**

```
function onDeviceReady()
 {

   var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "GRTDB", 3000000);

   db.transaction(queryRecommondedProduct, errorCB2, successCB);


  }

  function queryRecommondedProduct(tx){
    console.log("tx"+tx)
    try{
        //alert("SQL gonna run now");
       var progressHud =window.plugins.waitingDialog;
       progressHud.show("Loading...Please wait");
       tx.executeSql("Select aa.ProductID,aa.ProductName,aa.Price,aa.Description,aa.Specification,aa.VideoLink,ab.GalleryID,ab.Location,ab.ImageName,ab.LocalFolder,aa.Buy_Now from tblProduct aa inner join tblGallery ab on aa.ProductId=ab.ProductId where aa.ProductId=(select RecomProdId  from tblQuery where AnswerQ1='"+"townhouse"+"' AND  AnswerQ2='"+"small"+"' AND AnswerQ3='"+"several"+"' AND AnswerQ4='"+"medium duty"+"' AND AnswerQ5='"+"monthly"+"' AND IsDeleted='0' ORDER BY ProductAnswerId ASC LIMIT 1  ) and aa.IsDeleted ='0' and ab.IsDeleted ='0' and ab.IsDownLoad ='1'", [],function(tx,result){queryRecommdedSuccess(tx,result,"isReccom")}, errorCB4);   

    }
    catch(e){alert("test"+e);}
}
 function queryRecommdedSuccess(tx,result,rflag){

    console.log("Step2"+result.rows.length)
  // alert("Step2 - "+result.rows.length);
    if(result.rows.length>0){


    }
    }

function errorCB2(err){
    alert("Error2 is::--- "+err.code);
}


function successCB(){
}
 function **queryRecommded**()
 {

   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 }

 function openInapp(){

  iabRef = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
  iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
  iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
  iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
  iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem solved by using `_system` at the `target` value.

> window.open(**url**, **target**, **options**);

- **url:** the URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if you have Unicode characters in your URL.
- **target:** the target to load the URL in (String) (Optional, Default: "_self")
- **options:** options for the InAppBrowser (String) (Optional, Default: "location=yes")

`target` values:

```
_self - opens in the Cordova WebView if url is in the white-list, else it opens in the InAppBrowser
_blank - always open in the InAppBrowser
_system - always open in the system web browser
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to my need to create an `inAppBrowser` using `target= "_blank"` and returning using a Database connection, I decided to investigate deeply and I found a "fix" that works for me.

In source file (in my case is Android (InAppBrowser.java)) I just comment those lines being the result like this:

```
 
if (enableDatabase) {
    //String databasePath = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getDir("inAppBrowserDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
    //settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
      settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
                }
```

Comment: I just had the same issue, and your fix worked - thanks so much for posting it.