# Encoding JavaScript object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I've got the problem. I tried to encode JavaScript Object to JSON. Here is a preview image of my Sencha app database object:
[image: http://s11.postimg.org/ttelg6u0z/Przechwytywanie.png]

I need to put it into local session, so I must encode this object. I tried using:

1. *JSON.stringify(db)*

   and my result is only:
   *{"version":"1.0"}*
2. *Ext.Encode(db)* - it's Sencha's function 
   and in result I've got: 
   *undefinied*

*'db'* is an object from the screen.

In need to encode this object with all of data.

Please, help me

[EDIT]

Is any other way to convert JS object to string and put it into local or session storage? Because object can't be stored in session or local storage

Comment: Looks like `db` is not an object literal but a function / class instance

Comment: i don't think u can encode functions into json

Comment: Is any other way to convert JS object to string and put it into local or session storage? Because object can't be stored in session or local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify method doesn't convert functions or null/undefined variables, in your object you've only property "version" as a string value, other properties are functions and prototypes.

```
If undefined, a function, or an XML value is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).
```

to know more about JSON.stringify, you can read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

regarding the EXT, make sure that the db object identifies is declared in the ext scope.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This explain why it doesn't work. Is any method to convert JavaScript objects with properties, functions and prototypes into JSON?

Comment: @user2837459 the question here is why you want to convert a method to a string? if it's a library you can call it later, you'd better use the local storage for storing data only,
note: localstorage is limited storage, and parsing objects consumes processing.

Comment: Because I need to store object instance returned by openDatabase() method and use this after reload my application.

Comment: @user2837459 well, but you can reopen the connection when ever you need, why storing the connection variable?

Comment: In my app I'm opening and closing another webView and after that database objects returned from openDatabase() are different. So I've stored first instance of my database in global variable, but when I have to reload app this object dissapeared. That's why I want to store this connection variable.

Comment: @user2837459 what about storing only database connection parameters variables in object and stringify them, persist them to local storage?

Comment: It didn't help. I always used the same database connection parameters, but results were different.

Comment: @user2837459 interesting, how two local databases on one browser with the same name? aren't you use the following code to open connection?
dbconnect.db = openDatabase('dbname', '1.0',
                                'To do list extension database', 5 * 1024 * 1024);

Comment: check the following lib: https://code.google.com/p/html5-web-db/source/browse/trunk/dbConnectors.js

Comment: I've got the same problem like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871103/table-not-found-when-coming-back-from-in-app-browser-link-phonegap

But I can't resolve this like in this link

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Encode is intended to be used for route parameters, as you can see in [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/utility.html#util-urlencode) 
JSON.stringify is intended to be used for constructing JSON strings from javascript objects.

Both do different things, what are you trying to achieve here?

As for why Ext.Encode returns undefined: is 'db' an object, or is it something else? 
Maybe it's because you have function properties in your object. I don't know how Ext.Encode is implemented, but they might only allow simple properties.
That would explain why Ext.Encode doesn't work but JSON.stringify does. (JSON.stringify is a bit more lenient when it comes to function properties, etc.)

Comment: Yes, it's an object. I don't know why it's undefined. In Ext.Encode is posible to convert JS objects to JSON. Here's example: http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/utility.html#util-json